# Publishing on Azure a asp.net Core 2.0 WebApp with ReactJS on Development mode

Tags: reactjs, development-environment, asp.net-core-2.0, webpack-hmr

I've got a web app with asp.net Core 2.0 and ReactJS.
If I publish the app in Azure in a Production environment everything goes right.

But when I try to change it to Development (adding on the Application Settings the key ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with value Development) the app crashes at the startup.

More exactly on the Configure method trying to do this:

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true,
            ReactHotModuleReplacement = true
        });
    }
```

And it throws an error like this:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.
>   )
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
>
> NodeInvocationException: Attempt to connect to Node timed out after 60000ms.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance+d__13.MoveNext()

I tried to publish it locally but is the same that in Azure.

Any one could help me to configure it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone got around with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

We host our site in Azure as well and the solution for me was to add this config key/value to the Application settings.

Key: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 
Value: 6.9.1

I suppose you could also add it to your appsetting.json or web.config as well.

Answer (score 0):

ok after a long struggle I have found a way to overcome this issue.

1. First set the app settings in Azure WebApp Settings - WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION  with the latest version. In my case I have used the node version 8.9.4 matching my dev machine environment.
2. The Azure deploy task in VSTS has got a feature to run a script post deployment where we can run "npm i -g" which will pick the package.json file from the wwwroot folder.

Try this and update here.